# Multi-threading jobs that need to maintain order

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool

I have a c/c++ process that has a long queue and every element in this queue needs to be
sent to a multiple (TCP) servers. The single thread is an option that works, however it is slow.

I need to implement a multithreaded solution. My process does not know in advance the number
of servers. The first idea is to create one thread for every server. A manager thread reads
the new element in the queue finds the destination and dispatches to the thread that matches the destination.

**One important note. Jobs might be dependent. I don't want to executed job_10 if job_5 is not completed.** Order needs to be maintained.

First of all I would like your opinion on the issue. Second I am searching for C++ implementations for reference. Third I am looking for books/sources that describe similar issues.

Comment: what you mean? a fork for a new connection?

Comment: The real solution for this problem is [Asynchronous IO](http://think-async.com/)

Comment: I would suggest looking up thread pooling. The concept of "multi-threading" is generally perceived as thread-per-client. Thread-pooling is an efficient way to get rid of threads you may not need all of the time.

Comment: @RageD: I think in this context thread pooling is an implementation detail. It does relate to performance, which was the original motivation, but I think we're still very much at the design stage here and it's probably fair to assume that a pooling implementation will be relatively plug-in-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [`boost asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)? It supports the concept of a "thread pool", so rather than a single thread per server (that is synchronous), you can have a pool of threads handling a large number of connections asynchronously. Performance isn't too bad either...

Comment: Same. Saved me adding an answer. Thread creation is rather heavy, so you are much better off not ending them just to have to start up another one when the next request comes in.

Comment: the problem is that I also need to maintain order. For example job_1 goues to thread_1 and needs to be completed in order to job_2 to be send to the same connection.

Comment: depending on how heavy your objects in the queue are, can you not maintain a queue per connection? Then all a thread has to do is to dispatch an item from a given queue to the given destination and then process the next item. The ordering of items to be sent to a given destination is maintained by the queue...

Comment: or alternatively, store the set of connections a given item in the queue should be dispatched to, and clear this set out as the item is sent to each connection. once the set is empty, that item can be removed from the queue... anyways, multiple ways to solve that problem...

Answer (score 0):

How did you arrive at the conclusion that you need a multithreaded solution? What do you mean when you say that your single-threaded solution is "slow"? Do you mean that other processing (perhaps UI stuff?) is held up while the items are sent to the server? Or does the whole process just take too long?

Your description is ambiguous on this question: does each item need to be sent to all servers, or just to one? Seems like just one, but I'm not sure. If it must be sent to all, then the complexity of a multi-threaded solution increases greatly.

Can you remove an item from the queue once it's been sent, or do you need to wait for an acknowledgement from the server? If you must wait then your queue management will become tricky - you can't remove the item until it's been acknowledged, and so you'll have to mark it as pending somehow, and the thread that picks the next item from the queue will need to be sure it doesn't pick a pending item. And when the item has been sent successfully it will have to be removed from the queue, and this implies concurrent write access to the queue.

How do you handle errors? If an item can't be sent does it stay in the queue for later retry, or is it moved to a failed list, or is it just logged and discarded? In a multithreaded system you'll learn of the failure asynchronously, and that implies concurrent write access to the error handling procedure.

You say that your process doesn't know in advance how many servers there are. Can this number change during processing?

By all means look into multithreading, but you may find that your "slow" single-threaded solution serves your business needs best - easy to implement, and reliable. If not, then hopefully some of these questions will be helpful to you.

Comment: Each item needs to be sent to one server and I need to wait for an ACK. The errors cases are just logged and discarded. The client never knows in advance the number of servers. The single thread might be slow because there are large tcp timeouts. Eg we need to wait for 10 seconds sometimes...

Comment: Sending each item to only one server, and waiting for ACK: Nim's suggestions sound like a good fit. You also mentioned keeping the items in order - presumably that means ordering among those destined for a given server, not ordering among all items regardless of server?